# allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError

Tags: allennlp

`allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError:` `from_params` was passed a `params` object that was not a `Params`. This probably indicates malformed parameters in a configuration file, where something that should have been a dictionary was actually a list, or something else. This happened when constructing an object of type `<class 'allennlp.nn.initializers.InitializerApplicator'>`.

Comment: what is the question? this wording seems to be an answer.

Comment: Can you post the configuration file you were using when this happened?